# Conservation of probability in phase space flow

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism

In [J.Binney's notes on classical mechanics](http://www-thphys.physics.ox.ac.uk/people/JamesBinney/cmech.pdf), under the section 'Liouville's theorem', he states that (paraphrasing):

> the conservation of probability requires that $\frac{df}{dt} = 0.$

where $f$ is the phase space density.

I'm not sure why the probability is conserved. If we fix some initial phase space region $V_0$, which in time $t$ will become $V_t$, the probability of the system occupying that region is given by $$P_t = \int_{V_t} dxdp \ f(x,p;t).$$
But why is this constant in time? I know that the phase space volume is conserved, so at least the volume of the region won't change, but its shape will. What allows me to conclude that the function $f$ evolves in time in such a way that $P_t$ in fact remains constant?

Comment: The answer to your question is the proof of Liouville's theorem.

Comment: also time-evolution is linked to $\{H,f\}$, since the Hamiltonian is the infinitesimal generator

Comment: @RobinEkman well, the proof I've seen (http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/dynamics/four.pdf page 88) is not very illuminating to me, that 'version' of the theorem is that the volume is conserved. But I don't know how to prove the probability is, as well. It goes on to say "...since the volume elements $dxdp$ are preserved, we have $df/dt =0$". I don't see why.

Comment: @DepeHb did you see my answer? Liouville's theorem is Gauss like - see my answer. It's not that **volume** is conserved, it's that the **content** of the volume, if not constant, then there is a **flux**.

Comment: Well, by volume I don't mean a particular region of phase space, but rather its..well..volume, as in, measure, as it travels around in phase space. Volume in this sense is conserved.

Comment: I'll add now a small clarification in my answer, and maybe that will help you more. Please wait a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, no, you miss something. Let me show you in a simple way. Since your density function $f$ is a function of $x, p$ and $t$, its total derivative by time looks as follows,

(1) $\frac {df}{dt} = \frac {∂f}{∂t} + \frac{∂f}{∂x} \frac {dx}{dt} + \frac{∂f}{∂p} \frac {dp}{dt}$.

Do you agree?
This is what says [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(Hamiltonian)), i.e. that if the left-hand-side (LHS) is zero, then the right-hand-side (RHS) is zero.

Now let me integrate (1) on both sides

(2) $\frac {d}{dt} \int_{V_t} f(x, p; t) dx dp = \frac {∂}{∂t} \int_{V_t} f(x, p; t) dx dp + \int_{V_t} \frac{∂f(x, p; t)}{∂x} \frac {dx}{dt} dx dp + \int_{V_t} \frac{∂f(x, p; t)}{∂p} \frac {d p}{dt} dx dp$

$ = \frac {∂}{∂t} \int_{V_t} f(x, p; t) dx dp + \int_{V_t} \nabla f(x, p, t) \  \vec v \ dx dp$

Here, you apply a variant of the Divergence theorem, in fact, the energy conservation: the change of the total probability in a volume, due to transport with velocity $\vec v$ is equal to the total flux through the surface of the volume

$\int_{V_t} (\nabla f) \ \vec v \ dpdx = \int_{S_t} f \vec v$ • $\vec n \ dS$,

In all, we have similarity with Gauss' theorem : nothing "disappears". If the amount of energy confined to some volume **decreases**, then there is some **outwards flux**. Alternatively, if it **increases**, then some inwards flux exists there.

(I notice that you speak of a volume $V_t$ and I went with that, but in 1 dimension you have a surface, and my $S_t$ is then a contour - i.e. the flux is through the contour of the surface.)